# Synology + Git: empty repo cloned via WebDav

Tags: git, ssh, https, webdav, synology

I set up a "**git --bare --shared**" repo on my Synology NAS with SSH connection from local network via VPN (for security). 
I usually work via SSH and all it's fine.

Now i would to switch to HTTPS to avoid VPN connection but i receive the warning "You appear to have cloned an empty repository" via WebDav although the repo is not empty.

On my Syno and router i set up:

- git bare shared folder on /volume1/git
- valid HTTPS certificate
- port forwarding 443 (HTTPS) and 5006 (Webdav)

If i do a test in a browser with URL https://myddnsurl:5006/git/test.txt i could read the content of file.

But if i run "**git clone https://myddnsurl:5006/git/myprojectfolder.git**" and enter valid username & password i receive the warning

> You appear to have cloned an empty repository

Via browser i got:

> You don't have permission to access /git/myprojectfolder.git on this
>   server

Why? Is it a permissions problem?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I need 2 things:

1. On REMOTE: use a post-update hooks

> cd git/myprojectfolder/hooks 
>  
>   cp -p hooks/post-update.sample 
>  
>   ./post-update

2. On LOCAL: add username to https URL otherwise i got "error 22"

> git clone https://username@myddnsurl:5006/git/myprojectfolder.git

Now i can clone, push e pull via HTTPS!
I hope this help will be useful for somebody else.
Bye.